# Connected new charger with Macbook Pro. Both Macbook Pro and Charger stopped working. Any reasons?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, charger

My macbook pro charger stopped working sometime ago. In the meanwhile I have been using friend's charger without any problem.

Today I bought a second hand charger and when I tried to connect it with my Macbook, the charging light on charger blinked for few seconds and then stopped working. The Macbook Pro also stopped working and it doesn't turn ON, no matter how long I press the restart button.

The Macbook was 60% charged before I connected this new charger. So I am assuming the reason it stopped working is because I connected this new charger.

Any ideas, what could be happening?

Comment: what charger model did you get?

Answer (score 2):

Try resetting the SMC (System Management Controller) — the SMC controls many hardware features of the Mac and resetting it can fix problems such as a Mac not responding to the Power button:

> **Power**
>   The computer doesn't respond to the power button when pressed.

<sup>Source: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964</sup>

1. Connect your friend's known working charger.
2. Press ⇧⌃⌥ and the power button, then release all at the same time.

   The Mac shouldn't boot and will remain off. The LED on the MagSafe connector may change colour and/or flash briefly.
3. With the charger still connected, press the power button to turn your Mac back on.

Comment: Thanks. I did try this method and it didn't work. I actually ended up taking it to Apple Care so I guess it will be fine after that.